# Wildfly error too many open files, ulimit doesn't work

Tags: file, wildfly, ulimit

The problem : I have a Wildfly server for my web applications.
The server work during 1~2 hours and after a moment, I have this error for all the requests : Too many open files.

I have already put the ulimit nofile 65535 for all users and the same error appears.

How can I fix this error ?

Comment: Close some files?  It's pretty hard to answer you question with some more details.  Have you done an `lsof` to see if there are files/sockets open that you don't expect?

Comment: I have the same applications on a Jboss 4 and don't have the problem...
The `lsof` give me a lot of files